# Safari is not stopping the CSS3 animation

Tags: javascript, css, safari, css-animations

my target is to animate a loading spinner. After a ajax call is finished the spinner should finish the last rotation but stop than. In FF, Chrome and Opera it is working fine with just adding a class with

```
animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

but in Safari (11.1.2) it is still running.

I think it is just something small to change but I don't find it. My idea is that safari doesn't let me change the animation while running so I can't change.

Code:

```
   function stop()
   {
       document.getElementById("box").classList.add("stop");  
   }
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: animationRotateFrames linear 2s; 
    animation: animationRotateFrames linear 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;    
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.stop
{
    animation-iteration-count: 1;   
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
button
{
      margin-top: 40px;
    padding: 20px;
}

@-moz-keyframes animationRotateFrames{
  0% {
    -moz-transform:  rotate(0deg) ;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform:  rotate(359deg) ;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animationRotateFrames {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) ;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(359deg) ;
  }
}

@keyframes animationRotateFrames{
  0% {
    transform:  rotate(0deg) ;
  }
  100% {
    transform:  rotate(359deg) ;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="box"></div>

<button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
```

---

Just as a demo:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2fqjuabo/31/)

Comment: That actually sounds like a bug, even though I'm not sure, since their behavior makes sense: if the animation has iterated more than 1 time, they just ignore iteration-count... For a workaround, the only way I can think off would be by using js and listening to the `animationiteration` event to stop the animation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. With the event I want to clean the div from the animationen classes. With animationiteration it is working.
https://jsfiddle.net/2fqjuabo/74/